# align image to bottom when it doesn't fill the space allocated for <mx:Image>

Tags: apache-flex

I have an image that doesn't fill the `<mx:Image>` tag because it's not the exact dimensions (it is too short) and I have `maintainAspectRatio` set to true:

```
<mx:Image id="theImage"
          source="{data.photo_thumb}"
          horizontalCenter="0"
          verticalCenter="0" 
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          bottom="0"
          maintainAspectRatio="true"/>
```

The `<mx:Image>` tag has a fixed width and height (it's 100% of the tile size--this is in an ItemRenderer).  How do I get the image to sit on the bottom of the `<mx:Image>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`verticalAlign="bottom"`

Sometimes I'm putting images in the `Box`es to achieve greater control.

Comment: +1 for verticalAlign="Bottom".  I didn't know that was there.  But, how does a Box give you greater control?  Isn't it just either horizontal or vertical?  a Canvas or Container which offer absolute positioning give you the greatest control.

Comment: Box has paddings and I can set its size/position independent of the image. It's an extra wrapping, but there were times I could not get layout I needed without it.

Comment: It's not greater control than absolute positioning, just support for automatic layout (I don't like to mess with bindings.)

Comment: nice, thanks for the help, guys.  Flextras, your idea seems like it would work too...

Comment: A Container or Canvas brings all the benefits a Box does (padding / positioning independent of the Image), without the extra overhead of the layout logic.  If you need the layout logic, great, but if there is only one child (as in this case) it is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

A few things come to mind.  First, you have maintainAspectRatio to true.  This means that the Image's aspect ratio will always be maintained; so even with height and width it may never fill the complete space that is allotted for i.  So, an easy way to get the image to fill the whole space is to set maintainAspectRatio to false.  I don't think that quite addresses your question, though.

> How do I get the image to sit on the
>   bottom of the  tag?

I didn't think you could position the Image within an Image tag, although another poster mentioned using the verticalAlign style; which would be great if it worked.

What I would do do is position the image inside a container.  Conceptually something like this should work:

```
<Container id="myContainer">
 <mx:Image id="myImage" y="{myContainer.height=myImage.height}" />
</Container>
```

But, be careful about using data binding inside a renderer.  It often leads to a performance drag.